# Reading & Deleting Emails

Tags: c, linux, email, gnu, email-client

I have been attempting to use the GNU mailutils library but have had no end of problems just getting it installed and in a state of doing the email equivalent of 'Hello world'. I am also less than impressed with the documentation.

Could anyone suggest an alternative C library to read and delete local emails on a Fedora system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UW-IMAP c-client works for me.
http://www.washington.edu/imap/

It has some fairly good documentation, although the formatting/presentation could be better ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I came across UW-IMAP in my search but have been avoiding it because it seems so dated. In the absence of anything else I'll give it a try. I'm amazed there are not more libraries, or at least easier to find ones, available.